# STM32 LwIP netconn_write problem transmitting structs

Tags: c, tcp, stm32, ethernet, lwip

I am using LwIP stack with FreeRTOS in STM32F407Discovery board as TCP Client and I have a Linux computer as TCP Server. I faced a problem during transmission of a struct array, say `struct EncoderData Encoder[2]`, through `netconn` API.

The thing is, when I print the elements of the struct array to Serial Terminal (with UART) the data stored in the struct array is correctly shown. However when I send the structs through `netconn` socket, the elements of the first struct, i.e. `Encoder[0]` is received correctly, whereas `Encoder[1]` is received as all zeroes.

**Expected output in the Server side,**

```
Encoder[0] ---> 0xAA 0x07 0x00 0x52 0x12 0xDC 0xAB 0xFA
Encoder[1] ---> 0xAA 0x07 0x01 0x52 0x42 0xBF 0xAA 0xFA
```

**Resulting problematic output in the Server side**

```
Encoder[0] ---> 0xAA 0x07 0x00 0x52 0x12 0xDC 0xAB 0xFA
Encoder[1] ---> 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
```

Below, I am sharing both the server and the client side code, I would appreciate if you could help me out identifying the problem.

**Server.c -- Linux Computer**

```
#define MAX  9 
#define PORT 8080 
#define SA struct sockaddr 

#define NUM_OF_ENCODERS  2
#define PREAMBLE         0xAA
#define LENGTH           0x07
#define CRC              0xFA

struct EncoderData {
    volatile uint8_t encoderID;
    volatile uint8_t byte0;
    volatile uint8_t byte1;
    volatile uint8_t byte2;
    volatile uint8_t byte3;
    volatile uint8_t byte4;
    volatile uint32_t singleTurnValue;
    volatile uint16_t multiTurnValue;
    volatile uint16_t prevMultiTurnValue;
    volatile uint8_t direction;
    volatile float angle;
};

struct EncoderData Encoder[NUM_OF_ENCODERS];

// This function is called inside int main() 
void func(int sockfd) 
{ 
    uint8_t buff[MAX]; 
    uint32_t singleTurnValue = 0;
    float angle = 0.0;
    uint8_t channel;
    uint8_t encoderID;

    // infinite loop to read data continuously
    for (;;) { 

        bzero(buff, MAX); 

        // read the message from client and copy it in buffer 
        read(sockfd, buff, sizeof(buff));

        if(buff[0] == PREAMBLE && buff[1] == LENGTH && buff[8] == CRC)
        {
            encoderID = buff[2];

            Encoder[encoderID].encoderID        = encoderID;
            Encoder[encoderID].byte0            = (uint8_t)buff[3];
            Encoder[encoderID].byte1            = (uint8_t)buff[4];
            Encoder[encoderID].byte2            = (uint8_t)buff[5];
            Encoder[encoderID].byte3            = (uint8_t)buff[6];
            Encoder[encoderID].byte4            = (uint8_t)buff[7];
            Encoder[encoderID].singleTurnValue  = (uint32_t)((buff[5] << 16)|(buff[6] << 8)|(buff[7]));
            Encoder[encoderID].multiTurnValue   = (uint16_t)((buff[3] << 8)|(buff[4]));
            //printf("%d\n", encoderID);
            bzero(buff, MAX);
        }

        // Here I print the struct elements, below printf shows data correctly
        printf("0x%X 0x%X 0x%X 0x%X 0x%X 0x%X\t\t", 
                Encoder[0].encoderID, Encoder[0].byte0, Encoder[0].byte1,
                Encoder[0].byte2, Encoder[0].byte3, Encoder[0].byte4);

        // However below printf results in only zeroes
        printf("0x%X 0x%X 0x%X 0x%X 0x%X 0x%X\n", 
                Encoder[1].encoderID, Encoder[1].byte0, Encoder[1].byte1,
                Encoder[1].byte2, Encoder[1].byte3, Encoder[1].byte4);

    } 
}
```

**Client.c -- STM32F407Discovery**

```
#define NUM_OF_ENCODERS  2

struct EncoderData Encoder[NUM_OF_ENCODERS];

void Encoder_Process(void)
{   
    //float angle = 0.0;
    uint64_t encoderRawValue = 0;
    uint32_t singleTurnValue = 0;
    uint8_t channel = 0;

    for(channel = 0; channel < NUM_OF_ENCODERS; channel++)
    {
        selectChannel(channel);

        encoderRawValue = readEncoder();
        singleTurnValue = getSingleTurn(encoderRawValue);
        angle = calculateMotorAngle(singleTurnValue);

        Encoder[channel].preamble  = 0xAA;
        Encoder[channel].length    = 0x07;
        Encoder[channel].encoderID = channel;
        Encoder[channel].byte0     = (uint8_t)((encoderRawValue >> 32) & 0xFF);
        Encoder[channel].byte1     = (uint8_t)((encoderRawValue >> 24) & 0xFF);
        Encoder[channel].byte2     = (uint8_t)((encoderRawValue >> 16) & 0xFF);
        Encoder[channel].byte3     = (uint8_t)((encoderRawValue >> 8)  & 0xFF);
        Encoder[channel].byte4     = (uint8_t)((encoderRawValue     )  & 0xFF);
        Encoder[channel].crc       = 0xFA;
    }
}

// Convert Encoder struct into buffer
uint8_t* prepareEncoderData(struct EncoderData enc)
{
    static uint8_t buffer[9];

    memset(buffer, '\0', 9);

    buffer[0] = enc.preamble;
    buffer[1] = enc.length;
    buffer[2] = enc.encoderID;
    buffer[3] = enc.byte0;
    buffer[4] = enc.byte1;
    buffer[5] = enc.byte2;
    buffer[6] = enc.byte3;
    buffer[7] = enc.byte4;
    buffer[8] = enc.crc;

    return buffer;
}

static void tcp_client_netconn_thread(void *arg)
{ 
  struct netconn *conn; //, *newconn;
    struct ip_addr remoteipaddr, localipaddr;
  err_t err1, err2;
//  portCHAR pagehits[100] = {0};
    uint8_t channels;
    uint8_t *transmitBuffer;

    IP4_ADDR(&remoteipaddr, DEST_IP_ADDR0, DEST_IP_ADDR1, DEST_IP_ADDR2, DEST_IP_ADDR3);
    IP4_ADDR(&localipaddr, IP_ADDR0, IP_ADDR1, IP_ADDR2, IP_ADDR3);

  /* Create a new TCP connection handle */
  conn = netconn_new(NETCONN_TCP);

  if (conn!= NULL)
  {
    err1 = netconn_bind(conn, &localipaddr, PORT_NUMBER);
        err2 = netconn_connect(conn, &remoteipaddr, PORT_NUMBER);

    if (err1 == ERR_OK && err2 == ERR_OK)
    {
            printf("STM32F4 connected to the server!\n");

      while(1) 
      {

         for(channels = 0; channels < NUM_OF_ENCODERS; channels++)
         {
            Encoder_Process();
            transmitBuffer = prepareEncoderData(Encoder[channels]);
            netconn_write(conn, transmitBuffer, strlen((char*)transmitBuffer), NETCONN_COPY);

         }

        vTaskDelay(10);
        //netconn_delete(newconn);
      }
    }
    else
    {
      printf("can not bind netconn");
      printf("\terr code: %d", err1);
      printf("\terr code: %d\n", err2);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    printf("can not create netconn");
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `strlen` to measure the length of binary data that can have binary `\0` in the middle of it. You do that on the client side inside the `netconn_write` call.

Comment: @JacekŚlimok would you recommend ```sizeof``` ?

Comment: `sizeof` is going to return size of the pointer in this case which on stm32 is going to be 4. I'd recommend returning size of the data inside the buffer from the function, e.g. by passing a pointer to `size_t` into the function and writing to it from within the function. Another option would be to return a struct from the function that consists of `uint8_t*` buffer and `size_t` speficying its size.

Comment: @JacekŚlimok thanks, apparently the problem is ```strlen```, as you already pointed out.